# Android user clicks on file explorer to open a file with app

Tags: android, file, android-intent

I find a problem. Let say my app is a music player.

I use a file explorer to open an audio file. If the music player is not yet started. I can handle it with below code:

Inside OnCreate:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();        
if (action != null && action.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
    FilePath = intent.getData().getPath();          
        //do something
}
```

But if my music player is started, then OnCreate is not called, instead, OnResume will be called. However,  it will become Intent.ACTION_MAIN, rather than Intent.ACTION_VIEW. Then I try to

Inside OnResume:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();        
if (action != null && action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
    FilePath = intent.getData().getPath();          
        //do something
}
```

But there is a problem. In normal android activity, eg, Resume an app after it is hidden by another app, there is no intent.getData().getPath(). How should I modify the code to make it able to distinguish the case? Or what is the correct way to do so?

Comment: Is this of any help: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29. Otherwise the media player should implement a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: better to use shreadprefernce to store file path at both stage on pasuse on resume..and try to fetch file path and check if file path is null or not...i exactly not get what you want to to..can you specify briefly